# JavaScript no funciona, cuando publico en mi web

Tags: javascript, php, formularios

Tengo un formulario de contacto en HTML, que recopila informacion como nombre, email, fecha de ingreso y de salida. Esa información es enviada a mi email vía PHP. El problema está en que quiero validar algunos datos, como por ejemplo que:

- La cantidad de noches indicadas sean mayor a dos
- Que la fecha de salida sea mayor a la de entrada.... cosas básicas.

Para ello llamo a una rutina en JS muy sencilla que hace la verificación.

Hasta ahora todo bien, mi código HTML + JS + PHP, funciona en local host a la perfección, pero cuando subo los archivos a mi host remoto, en mi sitio web, pareciera que el script de JS es "salteado" y deriva directamente al archivo Php.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?.... No logro que funcione cuando está publicado....

```js
function validar(){
    var name, email, pax, message, fechain, fechaout, expresion, noches, now, hoy;

    name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    pax = document.getElementById("pax").value;
    fechain = document.getElementById("fechain").value;
    fechaout = document.getElementById("fechaout").value;
    message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    expresion = /^[-\w.%+]{1,64}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$/i;

    hoy = new Date();
    now = hoy.getFullYear() + '-' + ( hoy.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + hoy.getDate();

    //validación de fechas://
    var fecha1 = moment(fechain);
    var fecha2 = moment(fechaout);
    noches = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'days');   

        if(name === ""){
            alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
            return false; 
        }

        else if(fechain > fechaout){
            alert("Verifique la fecha de ingreso y de salida");
            return false; 
        }
            
        else if(noches < 2){
            alert("El mínimo de noches es 2");
            return false;
        }

        else if(noches > 15){
            alert("Verifique la fecha de ingreso y de salida")
            return false;
        }   
}
```

```css
body {
  /*background-image: url(/images/bosqueabedules.jpg);*/
  /*background-size: 100vw 100vh;*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}

form {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  /*background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
  padding: 9px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*margin-top: 20px;*/
  border-radius: 7px;
}

div {
}

h2 {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

textarea {
  min-height: 120px;
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#boton {
  background: forestgreen;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

#boton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 580px) {
  form {
    width: 95%;
  }
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#boton_cancelar {
  background-color: var(--bs-red);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Formulario de contacto responsive con HTML y CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&amp;display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles-form.css">
</head>
<body style="background: #d7c295;">
    <section></section>
    <div class="container" style="padding-left: 12px;">
        <h1 class="text-start" style="font-size: 52.64px;font-family: Lato, sans-serif;">Contacto</h1>
        <p class="text-start" style="font-size: 14px;">Por favor complete el siguiente formulario<br></p><html lang="es">
    <head>
    <title>Formulario de Contacto</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles-form.css">
    <script src="assets/js/validar.js"></script>
    <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
                <form action="php/sendEmail.php" method="post" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar();">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre"> 
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
                    <label>Fecha de ingreso:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="fechain" name="fechain" placeholder="Fecha de ingreso">
                    <label>Fecha de Salida:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="fechaout" name="fechout" placeholder="Fecha de salida">
                          <label>Pasajeros:</label>
                          <select id="pax" name="pax">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2"selected>2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                          </select>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje aqui!"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" name="submit" class="btn-enviar" ID="boton">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="btn-enviar" ID="boton_cancelar">
                </form> 
    </body>
</html>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/validar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El HTML está mal tienes como una página dentro de otra: html, body head...repetidos. Llamas al script vallidar dos veces...ordena el código.

Comment: Ya ordené el código y sigue sin funcionar cuando lo publico en mi web. Todas las pruebas locales, incluso si lo ejecutas aqui dentro de stack overflow, funcionan a la perfección. Pero no asi cuando lo sub a mi web, el JS es como que lo saltea y pasa derecho al Php.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo ordenar primero tu html, como el que te muestran en una de las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Tu HTML esta mal estas colocando entas llamando dos estructura html tienes que acomodarlo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Formulario de contacto responsive con HTML y CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&amp;display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles-form.css">
</head>
<body style="background: #d7c295;">
    <section></section>
    <div class="container" style="padding-left: 12px;">
        <h1 class="text-start" style="font-size: 52.64px;font-family: Lato, sans-serif;">Contacto</h1>
        <p class="text-start" style="font-size: 14px;">Por favor complete el siguiente formulario<br>
        </p>

        <form action="php/sendEmail.php" method="post" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar();">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre"> 
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
            <label>Fecha de ingreso:</label>
            <input type="date" id="fechain" name="fechain" placeholder="Fecha de ingreso">
            <label>Fecha de Salida:</label>
            <input type="date" id="fechaout" name="fechout" placeholder="Fecha de salida">
            <label>Pasajeros:</label>
            <select id="pax" name="pax">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2"selected>2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje aqui!"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" name="submit" class="btn-enviar" ID="boton">
            <input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="btn-enviar" ID="boton_cancelar">
        </form> 
        
    </div>
    <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/validar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```